# RHEL 8.2 cannot change/remove /home directory

Tags: rhel8

In my RHEL 8.2 box I want to remove the disk space from /home (/dev/VGSYSTEM/LVHOME).

I umount /home, mount /dev/VGSYSTEM/LVHOME in /mnt and try to move the only home directory in /mnt to /home... but `Operation not permitted`

```
# umount /home
# mkdir /home/example
mkdir: cannot create directory '/home/example': Operation not permitted
# ls -ld /home
drwxr-xr-x. 2 root root 6 Sep 18  2020 /home
# getenforce
Disabled
# lsattr -l /home  # output is empty
# chmod 000 /home
chmod: changing permissions of '/home': Operation not permitted
# mkdir /example   # No error
```

The root file system type is XFS.

Any ideas?

update: this issue happens with /opt, too

Comment: Is "/" immutable?

Comment: If "/" were immutable, `mkdir /example` would have failed, wouldn't it?

Comment: Yes, I missed that! Is /opt a separate mountpoint too? Can you provide the output of `cat /proc/self/mountinfo`

Comment: @Matthew Ife, thanks anyway for your help and interest

Comment: Please don't edit the solution into your question, post it as an answer instead and accept it when you are allowed to. Otherwise the question will stay in the system as unsolved forever.

Comment: @GeraldSchneider   Thanks

Answer (score 1):

/home and /opt actually ARE immutable but I did not realize because I assumed `lsattr -l /home` and `lsattr /home` would show the attributes of /home -- **big wrong assumption**

`lsattr -d /home /opt` does show the actual attributes

```
# lsattr -d /home /opt
----i--------------- /home
----i--------------- /opt
```